# Error when connecting to Sybase from VBScript - internal Client Library error

Tags: vbscript, connection-string, sybase

I am writing a VBScript that connects to a Sybase database, reads some data from a table and stores it in variables, then connects to a MS SQL server and inserts data into tables with the variable data that was stored earlier.

I'm not sure if this is relevant information but since I only have a 32-bit driver for connecting to Sybase ODBC, and since this VBScript is running on a 64-bit machine, I am running it via commandline but using the SysWoW64 cmd.exe and running it like this:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>cscript C:\My\Directory\MyVBScript.vbs
```

I am having trouble connecting to the Sybase database. I was originally having some issues with the connection string itself, but that seems to have been sorted out.

Here is the error message I get now, but I have no idea how to get past this one:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [SYBASE][ODBC Sybase
>   driver][Sybase]ct_connect(): user api layer: internal Client Library
>   error: HAFAILOVER:Trying to connect to server

---

Here's the script as it is now

```
Dim connStr, objConn

DataSource = "ICCM_PREVIEW"
ServerIP = "1.2.3.4"
Port = "1234" 
DBuser = "myUser" 
DBpwd = "myPassword" 
DBName = "myDatabase" 
Driver = "SYBASE ASE ODBC Driver"

connStr = ""
connStr = connStr &"Driver="& Driver &";"
connStr = connStr &"Data Source="& DataSource &";"
connStr = connStr &"Srvr="& ServerIP &","& Port &";"
connStr = connStr &"Database="& DBName &";"
connStr = connStr &"uid="& DBuser &";"
connStr = connStr &"pwd="& DBpwd &";"

Wscript.Echo connStr 

'Define object type
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Open Connection
objConn.open connStr
```

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you look at the solution here: http://geekswithblogs.net/baskibv/archive/2008/01/18/118690.aspx ?

Comment: Or here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1182044

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter "Srvr" is not a valid connection parameter and the "Port" key-value pair is required.

*Before*

```
connStr = connStr &"Srvr="& ServerIP &","& Port &";"
```

*After*

```
connStr = connStr &"Server="& ServerIP & ";"
connStr = connStr &"Port="& Port &";"
```

---

**Excerpt from [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302792(v=sql.110).aspx)**

[image]

**Using Connection parameters chart**

> Following is a list of connection parameters other than from the DSN
>   parameter that can be supplied to the ASE ODBC Driver

Excerpt from the User Guide for [Adaptive Server Enterprise ODBC Driver by Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20116.1500/pdf/aseodbc.pdf)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I have made the changes that you suggested and now I receive a different error. "Insufficient information to connect to the data source"

Comment: My connection string is as follows "Driver=SYBASE ASE ODBC Driver;Data Source=ICCM_PREVIEW;Server=1.2.3.4,1234;Database=myDatabase;UID=myUser;PWD=myPassword;"

Comment: I notice the required key-value pair for port is also missing. I will update the code.

Comment: Thanks so much @WorkSmarter. Unfortunately, the same error message occurs. Here's the new connection string: "Driver=SYBASE ASE ODBC Driver;Data Source=ICCM_PREVIEW;Server=1.2.3.4;Port=1234;Database=myDatabase;UID=myUser;PWD=myPas‌​sword;"

Comment: @robotsushi Add curly brackets around the driver value I.e. {SYBASE ASE ODBC DRIVER}. Similar to what is delivered here https://www.connectionstrings.com/adaptive-server-enterprise-odbc-driver/

Comment: I tried that as well, still the same error message. :/

Comment: What version of SYBASE are you running?

Comment: I'm trying to confirm but apparently this information is difficult to acquire as it is not on my local machine, but a remote server. It's from 1999. I'm almost certain it is ASE version 12.

Comment: Take a look at this article and how they added error coding http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1067909-ODBC-Connection-Status.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But your diligence was instrumental in me solving this issue. Unfortunately it was so long ago I do not recall what the solution was, but I remember that your guidance helped so much. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.